# Copying a class with a reference to a derived object

Tags: c++, polymorphism

Let's say I have three classes, one abstract class, a derived class and a class that contains the derived class.

```
class Parent {
public:
  Parent();
  void FunctionOne() { cout << "error"; }
  void FunctionTwo() = 0;
}

class Child : public Parent {
public:
  Child();
  void FunctionOne() { cout << "implement function one" ;}
  void FunctionTwo() { cout << "implement function two" ;}
}


class Execute{
public:
  Execute(Parent& newparent) : parent(newparent) ;
  Execute& operator=(const Execute& in) {
          parent = in.parent;
  Run() { parent.functionOne(); parent.functionTwo(); }

private:
  Parent& parent;
}
```

When I create my object Execute everything is fine.

```
Excecute execute( Child );
execute.run();
```

Output: "implement function one" "implement function two"

The problem is that when I add it to a vector, Execute is being copied, which is copying Parent, but instead of copying Child to parent and using polymorphism, Parent is copying a abstract class and my output is "error" and my program crashes.

```
vector<Execute> list;
list.push_back( Execute( Child ) );
list[0].run();  // ERROR
```

Is there away to copy references so the Child class is copied?  Do I need to switch to pointers?  The problem is that since Execute is being copied I don't have an easy way to manage the deletion of the pointer to Child.  I cannot use Boost or shared_ptr<> on this machine.

I added inheritance to my post sorry for leaving that out.  I think I fixed the problem with Excecute execute( Child );  My apologies, I was trying to simplify the problem to make it to understand and may have introduced some subtle errors.  Can you please help me with my original problem?

Comment: Your code doesn't have inheritance. Could you fix it to reflect your issue?

Comment: `Excecute execute( Child() );` most certainly does NOT do what you seem to think it does. It doesn't create an object, instead it declares a function.

Comment: your need to pick between reference, pointer and value semantics.  Currently you are using reference semantics and experiencing object slicing.  What does `=` mean?  That is something only you can answer.

Comment: I understand what you mean but I am not quite clear how to go about it.  I would like parent to be a reference for the original object, in this case child.  I know that I am copying a "slice" of child into parent, which is not what I want.  But is there a way to do what I want?  I'm not sure so turned to here for help.

Comment: You haven't said what you want to do on `=`, so how can I determine if it is possible to do what you want?  Suppose have have `Execute one(alice);` and `Execute two(bob);`: what do you want `one=two` to do?  Not the implementation details, but what *abstractly* do you want it to *mean*.

Answer (score 0):

First, you are storing the reference to a temporary in the class.  As soon as you go outside the current scope, anything you do with that instance of `Execute` would be operating on an invalid reference.

To fix this:

```
class Execute
{
public:
    Execute(Parent* newparent) : parent(newparent) {}
    Execute(const Execute& e) : parent(e.parent) {} // for the rule of 3

    ~Execute() {} // empty destructor - since you didn't create it, you shouldn't delete it

    Execute& operator=(const Execute& in) 
    {
        parent = in.parent;
        return *this;
    }

    Run() 
    {
        parent.functionOne(); 
        parent.functionTwo(); 
    }

private:
  Parent* parent;
};
```

Then, when you use it:

```
Parent* p = new Child();
// to show the scoping doesn't destroy p
{
    Execute e(p);
    e.Run();
}
delete p;
```

You can pass around `Execute` instances in any container and it won't invalidate a valid `parent` member for another instance.  But when you are done with them, you have to clean them up yourself.

Comment: Thanks for this but in my case parent and execute will only exist in the same scope.  If possible I would like to avoid "naked" new pointers.  Do you have any advice?

Comment: You'll need to use pointers in some fashion (see http://msujaws.wordpress.com/2009/05/04/my-notes-on-more-effective-c-by-scott-meyers/ for why references won't work for your goal).  If you cannot use `std::shared_ptr` or `std::unique_ptr`, then you'll need to either write your own smart pointer class or handle the memory yourself.

Answer (score 0):

If all errors are fixed and functions are declared as virtual and code can be compiled the behavior is as expected:

```
implement function oneimplement function two
```

As you mention parent is a reference to some "original" object. This object has to be either dynamically allocated or global or automatic but living longer than Execute/vector. Or you can change the parent to ordinary member variable, not reference.

```
Child c;
vector<Execute> list;
list.push_back( Execute( c ) );
list[0].Run();
```